# PHP Trouble renaming array key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am reading hundreds of CSVs to import into a DB.

Some of the column names contain the same data but have different names across all the files.

For example, one file will say Phone where the other says EveningPhone...both contain the same data, different names.

I am trying to rename everything to EveningPhone because I had most of the code done when i realized there were different header names in different files.  Too lazy to replace all i guess..

I am creating an assoc array to match the data then off to the db it goes..

The problem is I cannot get the keys to rename to one convention.   Here is the function where it happens:

```
public function readCSV($file) {
    /**
     * @todo: LOAD THE FILE INTO A MULTIDIMENSIONAL ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY TO DETERMINE THE FILEDS
     */

    // Read the first line to get the headers
    $headers = fgetcsv($file);


    if (!array_key_exists('EveningPhone', $headers)) {
        if (array_key_exists('Phone', $headers)) {
            $headers['EveningPhone'] = $headers['Phone'];
            unset($headers['Phone']);
        } else {
            die("other");
        }
    }

    format::neat_r($headers);   // basically print_r but adds a new line to read it easier...
    die();
```

The array is returned before and after as this:

```
LeadID
```

AddDate
LastName
FirstName
Address
City
State
ZipCode
LeadLocator
Phone
Email
Sex
Comments

At the end, I still get EveningPhone not defined errors from a file that uses Phone as the phone number..

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted seems to be okay, are you sure the problem lies in this specific snippet?

Comment: Could you post here cvs file?

Comment: Both before and after I get the array returned.  I posted it in the original post.

Comment: Could you post this cvs in `<pre>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgetcsv does not return an associative array.  It will return an array with the data as values so you should be using in_array or array_search (when you need the key).  The code that reads the actual data is probably using array_combine to build an associative array using the header.

```
public function readCSV($file) {
    /**
     * @todo: LOAD THE FILE INTO A MULTIDIMENSIONAL ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY TO DETERMINE THE FILEDS
     */

    // Read the first line to get the headers
    $headers = fgetcsv($file);


    if (!in_array('EveningPhone', $headers)) {
        if ($phoneKey = array_search('Phone', $headers)) {
            $headers[$phoneKey] = 'EveningPhone';
        } else {
            die("other");
        }
    }

    format::neat_r($headers);   // basically print_r but adds a new line to read it easier...
    die();
```

Comment: Thats it!  Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
 if (!in_array('EveningPhone', $headers)) {
```

because the `$headers` array is a normal indexed list after you just read it via `fgetcsv`. Therefore array_key_exists won't work. You might later use it as dict, but at this point it isn't yet an array key.

To replace the entry use:

```
 $headers[array_search("EveningPhone", $headers)] = "Phone";
```

Comment: Right!) And your must replace item like using `array_search` or use cycle